# How does Python determine which type to cast something to?

Tags: python, casting, comparison

Suppose I have the following:

```
x = "0"
y = 0
if x == y:
    print "You're winner!"
```

Will Python convert `x` to an int, or `y` to a string? Is there any way to control this behavior?

Comment: Neither. That will return `False`.

Comment: `x == str(y)` or `int(x) ==y` ... or `str(x) == str(y)` or `int(x) == int(y)` basically it does what you tell it to ... however `"0" == 0` is `False`

Comment: Python  is not javascript

Comment: So Python won't make any attempt to implicitly convert these? Would it throw an error in this case?

Comment: If you write `x==str(y)`, it will return `True`

Comment: No, it won't throw an error. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I have... I would almost rather it throw an error. Makes it very difficult to find errors such as these.

Comment: Python doesn't consider this usage an error.  If you want behavior like that, you can make your own equality tester, but it goes against community-established standard idioms.  You might prefer a statically typed language, most of which work more closely to what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python doesn't do any typecasting for you.  If you want to control it, then you should be explicit.

---

Note that just because python doesn't do any typecasting for you, various objects *might*.  In this case, all of the magic is in the `__eq__` method for `int` and `str`.  When python sees:

```
a == b
```

It will try:

```
a.__eq__(b)
```

If that returns `NotImplemented`, it will then try `b.__eq__(a)`.  Otherwise, the return value of `a.__eq__(b)` will be returned and used as the result of the comparison.  Obviously there are analogous "dunder" methods for other types of comparisons (`__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, etc).

Very few builtin objects allow comparisons to different types -- in fact, the only builtin objects that I can think of off the top of my head that allow those sorts of shenanigans are `int` and `float` because most people expect `1.0 == 1` to be `True`...

Also note that (for equality) most of the default comparisons return `False` if the types don't match.  No error is raised.  For other, more rich comparisons (e.g. `__lt__`, `__gt__`) the result is actually version dependent.  Python2.x orders based on the type.  It guarantees a consistent (but arbitrary) ordering.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '1' > 1
True
```

Python3.x does a smarter thing and disallows it completely by raising a `TypeError`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '1' > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is a strongly typed language. Barring a few exceptions with `float` types and `int` types involving arithmetic, Python does not convert types.

Answer (score 1):

No conversion will happen.  `x` and `y` are not equal since they are different types.  If you want to control equality testing, you can implement the "magic" `__eq__` method on your object.  There is no implicit conversion feature.

Answer (score 1):

It won't convert either; it will just decide that they're not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do these:
1. cast `x` to `int`:

```
x = "0"
y = 0
if int(x) == y:
    print "You're winner!"
```

2. cast `y` to `str`:

   `x = "0"
   y = 0
   if int(x) == y:
       print "You're winner!"`